# Delete ALL text to the right of a particular character in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following value in an Google Spreadsheet.

```
A1  abcd/defg/xyz/abc
A2  ghtht/sdfsd
A3 dsfdsf/sdfsdfa/erere/dfdf/erer/sdfsdfs
```

What forumla or script should I use that I get

```
B1 abcd/defg/xyz
B2 ghtht
B3 dsfdsf/sdfsdfa/erere/dfdf/erer
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will remove the right-most instance of the forward slash, and everything to the right of it:

`=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"^(.*)/[^/]*$")`

Comment: Thanks Adam. It worked perfectly. Any suggestions on how to delte to the left of it. Sorry I am bad with regex :(

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136) function to parse the string, delete the last cell, and append the string back using CONCATENATE function. Else you can write a script to parse and manipulate the string as you wanted using Apps script, which is just JavaScript. Here is the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets) on how to read and write from Spreadsheets in Appscript.

Hope that helps!